# Finding a coordinate transformation to diagonalize the metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I'm reading a solved problem which states that we have a bidimensional metric space whose metric is
$$
ds^2 = dv^2 - v^2 du^2
$$
and we want to find a coordinate transformation such that we get the Minkowski's bidimensional metric space
$$
ds^2 = dx^2 - dt^2\ .
$$

The solution involves equating both metrics,
$$
dv^2 - v^2 du^2 = dx^2 - dt^2\ .
$$
Then, for $x = x(u, v)$ and $t = t(u, v)$ we have
$$
dx = \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u} du + \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v} dv \quad\text{and}\quad dt = \dfrac{\partial t}{\partial u} du + \dfrac{\partial t}{\partial v} dv\ .
$$
Substituting these expressions in the equality of the metrics, we arrive at a system of partial differential equations.

The solution keeps going stating that we can solve the system with the method of variable separation,
$$
x(u, v) = U(u) V(v) \quad\text{and}\quad t(u, v) = T(u)S(v)\ ,
$$
leading to the system
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l} U'^2 V^2 - T'^2 S^2 = -v^2 \\ V'^2 U^2 - S'^2 T^2 = 1 \\ UU' VV' = TT'SS' \end{array} \right.
$$

I understand the following step, which is realizing from the third equation that
$$
\dfrac{UU'}{TT'} = \dfrac{SS'}{VV'} = \text{constant}\ ,
$$
but suddenly the proposed solution is like "from this we instantly get"
$$
x(u,v) = v \cosh u \quad\text{y}\quad t(u,v) = v \sinh u\ .
$$

I wonder if someone could give a more detailed step by step solution for this system of differential equations, or any hint about how to proceed. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm presenting my overall thought process as I went through the derivation. There might well be a simpler way to go about it. We start with
$$
ds^2 = dv^2 - v^2 du^2 = v^2 [ \frac{dv^2}{v^2} - du^2 ] = v^2 d ( \ln v - u ) d ( \ln v + u )
$$
Define
$$
u+\ln v = U , \qquad u - \ln v = V ~~\implies~~ u = \frac{1}{2}(U+V) , \qquad \ln v = \frac{1}{2} ( U - V ) 
$$
The metric is
$$
ds^2 = - e^U e^{-V} dU dV = d(e^U) d(e^{-V})
$$
Next, we define
$$
e^U = x + t , \qquad e^{-V} = x - t . 
$$
The metric is now
$$
ds^2 = (dx+dt)(dx-dt) = dx^2 - dt^2.
$$
This is the final form of the metric you want. We can now eliminate $U$ and $V$ and directly determine the relationship between $(t,x)$ and $(u,v)$
$$
v^2 = e^{U} e^{-V} = (x+t)(x-t) = x^2-t^2 \implies v = \sqrt{x^2-t^2}
$$
and
$$
u = \frac{1}{2} ( U + V ) = \frac{1}{2} \ln(x+t) - \frac{1}{2} \ln (x-t)  = \frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{x+t}{x-t} . 
$$
Inversely,
$$
x = v \cosh u , \qquad t = v \sinh u . 
$$